# Use of the word other

Tags: grammaticality

Ben is a dog.

Is the following sentence OK?

"We will feed Ben and other cats at 5pm."

Comment: What message dId you intend the sentence to convey?

Comment: If Ben is not a cat, _other_ makes no sense; just say '...and the cats'.

Comment: @Lawrence That in addition to feeding Ben, other animals (cats) are also fed.

Comment: @KateBunting Yes, though we just don't know how many other cats will turn up. So we're not sure whether "and the cats" could be used for an indeterminate number.

Comment: But they are not _other cats_ if Ben is a dog! You have to say either _other animals_ or _any cats which turn up_.

Answer (score 1):

@KateBunting has the following accepted answer:

You have to say either other animals or any cats which turn up.